# Odoo generate dynamic child model with parent model fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, odoo, odoo-16

Is there any way to give user an option generate dynamic model (Table on Database)?

Suppose I have a model name Data which has four fields name, latitude, longitude and properties. When user create a data object and add some properties field to this I want to generate child model with fields in properties from Data model. User will be able add entries to the child something like as add data line in picture attached and columns are value of properties.

If possible, How can I achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: You can create `ir.model` record and a relational field to `Data`model